# group shapes so I can cycle through them with mouse clicks - processing and java

Tags: java, processing

I have the code shown below which can show 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 circles around a larger circle, each equally spaced.

I know the code is written a long way, but I don't know the shorter way to code the values - how to let the code work out the coordinates for me.

My question is in two parts.

1. How can I group the code so that the first 2 ellipses are a group, the second three ellipses are a group and so on?
2. How can I cycle through the groups eg, 
   left mousebutton press = group moves back one
   right mousebutton press = group moves forwards one

I have been reading about how to create groups of shape but can see how to do it? If I were able to do that, I think I would have a fighting chance of writing the code if left mouse button pressed, display image+1 etc.

```
    int b, w;
void setup () {
  size (600, 600); //size of the sceen
  background (255, 255, 255); //colour of the screen
  b = 0; //sets value of b
  w = 255; //sets value of white
  //frameRate (1);
  fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (300, 410, 20, 20);

  // above is for 2 ellipses
/*
fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (395.2627944, 355, 20, 20);
  ellipse (204.7372056, 355, 20, 20);

  //above is for 3 ellipses

fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (410, 300, 20, 20);
  ellipse (300, 410, 20, 20);
  ellipse (190, 300, 20, 20);

  //above is for 4 ellipses

fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (404, 266, 20, 20);
  ellipse (364, 388, 20, 20); 
  ellipse (235, 388, 20, 20);
  ellipse (195, 271, 20, 20);

  //above is for 5 ellipses

fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (395, 245, 20, 20);  
  ellipse (395, 355, 20, 20);
  ellipse (300, 410, 20, 20);
  ellipse (204, 355, 20, 20);
  ellipse (204, 245, 20, 20);

  //above is for 6 ellipses

fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (386, 231, 20, 20);  
  ellipse (407, 324, 20, 20);
  ellipse (348, 399, 20, 20);
  ellipse (252, 399, 20, 20);
  ellipse (192, 324, 20, 20);
  ellipse (214, 231, 20, 20);

  //above is for 7 ellipses

fill (b);
  ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
  ellipse (378, 222, 20, 20);  
  ellipse (410, 300, 20, 20);
  ellipse (378, 378, 20, 20);
  ellipse (300, 410, 20, 20);
  ellipse (222, 378, 20, 20);
  ellipse (190, 300, 20, 20);
  ellipse (222, 222, 20, 20);

  //above is for 8 ellipses
  */
}

void draw() {

  //fill (w);
  //ellipse (width/2, height/2, 200, 200); // the guide circle. Not needed in final code.
}
```

haven't I already created each circle as a shape? (I'm a struggling novice here!).

I have wondered if I'd be able to do it this way instead.
Can I create a variable for each ellipse. Then call each ellipse (or several) at a key press.

Something like

```
int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6;
void setup() {
size (600,600);
background (255,255,255);
c1 = ellipse (300, 190, 20, 20);
c2 = ellipse (300, 410, 20, 20);
//etc

}

void draw() {

if '+' pressed, show c1, c2

if '+' pressed again, show c1, c3, c4

if '+' pressed again, show c1, c2, c5, c6

}
```

Comment: Lookinto the Shape API, create each circle as a shape and put them into a List, you cause the contains method of the Shape to determine if the mouse point is with the bounds of the Shape

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to comment but can't find how to show code in the comments so will post an answer to he question.

Comment: There is a base class called Shape, which includes Rectangle and Ellipse2D, which will do all the work you want

Comment: how do i use that base class?

Can you link me to a tutorial? Feeling very stuck!

Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @mikeeustace clarify if you're using plain Java or Processing. And remove the tags accordingly please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is not to reinvent the wheel where you can.

Java Swing has a geometry API, take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more details.

You can create a group of shapes by either using a `Map` or `List` or combination of both, depending on your needs

```
List<Shape> group = new ArrayList<Shape>(25);
group.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(300, 190, 20, 20));
group.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(300, 410, 20, 20));
```

You could then group the groups using a `Map` or another `List`, but that will come down to your needs...

Now, the benefit of this is you get a lot of extra functionality, for example, you and transform the shape, changing it's location or rotation, should you want to, but you also get some additional functionality to determine if a given point falls within the shape

By using a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), you can capture the `mouseClicked` event and loop through your collections...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
    for (Shape shape : group) {
        if (group.contains(evt.getPoint())) {
            // The shape was clicked...
        }
    }
}
```

The shape API is also supported by the `Graphics2D` API, allowing you to draw and/or fill the shapes simply by passing the reference of the shape it.

Comment: I think the OP is using Processing. One has to be careful using Swing and Processing together: https://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html There is a problem with posters using both Processing and Java tags for questions that are only related to Processing. This generates problems and confusions. For Swing, great answer btw.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Thanks for the uodate, think the question was only tagged as Java when I stumbled across it or it was late and need to get some sleep :P